# How to build a query for dbpedia for Politically Exposed Persons

Tags: semantic-web, dbpedia

I am trying to build a free API service for small businesses to access and perform checks of their customers against a list of Politicaly Exposed Persons (definition here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politically_exposed_person).

I have checked the data provided by blue chip vendors and they are essentially scraping wikipedia and  charging businesses tens of thousands to access this public data which is a shame and a scam.

So I was wondering if anyone would be willing to help me build the right query to extract as many living politicians, judges and there immediate parents (spouse, children, parents, siblings) names and details to build this list. My very preliminary findings show that they are either classified as OfficeHolders or Politicians.

Also, I noticed that there are stubs about politicians that do not appear in this extraction  (http://web.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/DBpediaAsTables/DBpediaClasses.htm)

So if anyone could help me here, this would be great, I am trying to make opensource data available to efficiently fight corruption.

Comment: I think you'll need to come up with a more precise specification, first.  It's not hard to write a query that selects all OfficeHolders and Politicians, but it's not clear whether that's what you're asking for, if you want something more.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for your response. So to be more accurate I would need the portrait picture's URL, name, first name, nationality, date of birth, current position of all living people under the categories "politicians", "officeholders", "judges". I would also need the same details of the living family members of these people (spouse / parents / children). Hope this is the level of detail that you need. If not, just let me know.